# UITabBarController's tabs' rotation and willRotateToInterfaceOrientation propagartion

Tags: ios

My app has four tabs: **A**, **B**, **C** and **D**.  Their `UIViewController` are managed by `UITabBarController`.  The app supports rotation, and so each view controller returns `YES` to `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

Using springs and struts, most of the rotation is done automatically by iOS.  However, tab **A** also requires further positioning, and it is done in its VC's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

When the VC for tab **A** is selected and the screen is rotated, that VC receives a `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` message (propagated by iOS from `UITabBarController`), and the resulting rotation is correct.

However, when the selected tab is **B** and the screen is rotated, **A**'s `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` is not called.  Makes sense.  But if I then select tab **A**, I get only the results of applying its springs and struts, without the post-processing done by its `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

After struggling with this for a while, and after failing to find a solution online, I came up with the following.  I subclassed `UITabBarController` and in its `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` I call all the VCs' `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` regardless of which one is the `selectedViewController`:

```
- (void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    if (self.viewControllers != nil) {
        for (UIViewController *v in self.viewControllers) 
            [v willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    }
}
```

It works, but it looks like a hack, and my question is whether I was doing the right thing.  Is there a way to tell iOS to always call a VC's `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` before displaying it for the first time after a screen rotation?

Comment: The viewController for tab **A** should have a `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method.  In it you could check the current orientation and make any necessary layout adjustments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to handle custom layout is by subclassing `UIView` and overriding the `layoutSubviews` method.  The system sends `layoutSubviews` to a view whenever its size is changed (and at other times).  So when your view A is about to appear on screen with a different size (because the interface was rotated while view B was on screen), the system sends view A a `layoutSubviews` message, even though it doesn't send view controller A a `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` message.

If you are targeting iOS 5.0 or later, you can override the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method of your `UIViewController` subclass and do your layout there, instead of subclassing `UIView`.  I prefer to do it in my view's `layoutSubviews`, to keep my view-specific logic separate from my control logic.

It's also a bad idea to do layout in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` because the system sends that message before actually changing the size of the view, and before the rotation animation block.  It sends the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:`, `layoutSubviews`, and `viewDidLayoutSubviews` messages inside the rotation animation block, so the repositioning of your subviews will be animated if the view is on screen during the rotation.

Comment: Thank you very much, @RobMayoff.  Your solution is cleaner and easier than the hack I came up with.  Not only that, but as you correctly pointed out, the rotation animation is now correct.  Before, the objects that were custom-positioned did not participate in the animation.  They just appeared in their new position while the non-custom objects animated.